# Webview actionsheet cancel button closes the ViewController

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview, uiactionsheet

In webview (be it UIWebview or WKWebview) I have an attachment button on which when clicked will open an actionsheet to open camera or choose images from library and a default cancel button.

When the app is installed for the first time, clicking on this attachment button brings up the actionsheet and when I choose cancel, then viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear of the present VC which has this webview is called and a VC from another storyboard is displayed (I have 3 storyboards in total) - (See update)

Again I have to pass through different VCs to get to this webview and if i again click on actionsheet and now if i select either options, 'from library', 'from camera' or 'cancel' option the same problem persists.

But when the app is stopped or quit from the background and is run again, this issue seems to vanish off.

Could yo pls let me know what am I doing wrong here or is there anything that can be done as a workaround???

**Update** - Actionsheet cancel button when clicked gets back to a ViewController which has no TabbarController or Navigation bar or both.
I made a sample with each one seperately and found the same issue with either of them.

Note: This is done in Swift 2.3

Comment: I have the same problem. When I test it with Xcode, there is no problem but when I download the same from App Store, it dismisses the wkwebview controller and comes back to the first one. Were you wble to solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, not yet.. It seems like a bug in UI/WK webview. This dosen seem to be a prob in Safari API. If intersted or if it suits your requirement, try using Safari ViewController API. Here's an intro to SafariAPI (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/504/) - but this has its own disadvantages..!

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in iOS 11. 
It can be solved by pushing the WKWebview controller or changing the presentation style of the modal presentation to be `currentContext`.